# Displaying a Xamarin.Forms.Maps map on a Android.App.Activity project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently programming a Android app using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to create a Google Maps object (using Xamarin.Forms.Maps) and then displaying this on my page. All of the pages so far have been made using the Android.App.Activity class type such as:

```
public class MapPage : Activity, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
```

Inside the OnCreate function that is called when you load the page I have created a button that when pressed generates a Map object:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MapPageView);
        Android.Widget.Button mapDisplay = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.addProperty);

        mapDisplay.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            GetAddress(); // GETS THE USERS ADDRESS
            Map userMap = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(lan, lon), Distance.FromMiles(1)));

            string url = "DATABASEURL";
            JsonValue json = await FetchUserAsync(url);
            var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
            string jsonString = json.ToString();
            var addressList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(jsonString);

            foreach (var mapPoint in addressList.Where(a => a.city.Equals(usersAddress.Locality)))
            {
                string address = mapPoint.address1 + ", " + mapPoint.address2 + ", " + mapPoint.city + ", " + mapPoint.postcode;
                var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);
                var latitude = point.Latitude;
                var longitude = point.Longitude;
                var userPin = new Pin()
                {
                    Position = new Position(latitude, longitude),
                    Label = mapPoint.address1
                };

                userMap.Pins.Add(userPin);
            }


            var userPosition = new Pin()
            {
                Position = new Position(lan, lon),
                Label = "You"
            };

            userMap.Pins.Add(userPosition);
            mapDisplay.SetOnClickListener(this);
        };

    }
```

This code basically runs through a list of addresses taken from a phpmyadmin database and converts them into lat/long pins and adds them to my map.

The bit I am stuck on is actually adding the Map to the page after it has been created. I have seen posts about using ContentPages and the like however this doesn't seem to be a feature inside the Android Activity class.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: why are you using a XF Map in an Android project?  Why not use a regular Android map?

Comment: it would be much easier if you put the map in another View/Activity... for example, click MapDisplay then open a new view/Activity with the map already rendered, then just populate it with the Pins.

Comment: @Jason what Android map would you suggest using? Pretty new to Xamarin so this was just the first one I found that seemed easy to use

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/